# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I am learning how to write unit-test. 
app.py:

```
class MyClass:
    def add(self):
        return 2+2
```

app_test.py:

```
import app
import unittest

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(app.add(), 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Command for run: `python -m unittest app_test.TestMyClass`.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_test.py", line 6, in test_add
    self.assertEqual(app.add(), 4)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: please post your project directory structure

Comment: `app.py` doesn't have function `add()`, but the class `MyClass` from that module has method `add()`, hence the error

Comment: Obviously you've imported `app.py`, and this module has indeed no `add` attribute. Maybe you should write something like `from app import MyClass` then test `self.assertEqual(MyClass.add(), 4)`

Comment: In your code, `app` refers to the module, not the class.  You need to create an instance: `m = app.MyClass()` and then call `m.add()` in your test code.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is calling `add()` directly, when it's an object method. Create an object first. This should work.

```
from app import MyClass
import unittest

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        o = MyClass()
        self.assertEqual(o.add(), 4)
```